# Async Function leaving array blank outside of scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I'm working with an async function to try and pull data into an Array with Axios. When I log the data inside the forEach below, it shows up, but when I log it outside the forEach, it returns blank. I assume this is because the program is still running, but I'm not sure how to solve without a timeout.

```
const user = async(IDs) => {

    var output;
    var URL;
    var result = [];

    IDs[0].forEach(async(id) => {
        URL = "https://example-api.com/" + id;
        output = await axios.get(URL)
            .then(function(data){
                result.push(data.data.text);
                console.log(result) // Returns the data
            });
    })

    console.log(result) // returns blank

}
```

Comment: use for of instead of forEach

Comment: It's simply not working because you're calling an async function inside foreach loop.. to make it work just add `await` just before your `IDs[0].foreach` line and everything will work

Comment: there are multiple mistakes like using `asycn` on a forEach loop. Then you use `.then()` with `await` that also dont really make sense

Comment: Also relevant: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   const user = async(IDs) => {
    var output;
    var URL;
    var result = [];

    for (const id of IDs[0]) {
        URL = "https://example-api.com/" + id;
        try {
            output = await axios.get(URL);
            result.push(data.data.text);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Give it a try

Answer (score 3):

All other solutions are good but they are fetching data one by one and this makes your code a little slower.

Use this approach as it'll take full advantage of event-loop and this will execute your program much faster.

```
const result = await Promise.all(IDs[0].map(id => {
  return axios.get(`https://example-api.com/${id}`)
    .then(data => (data.data.text)) 
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shubham has proposed the most efficient solution (`Promise.all` and `Array.map`), however, combining `async` / `await` with `Promise.then` can kill readability, especially as complexity increases.

Where possible, `await` should be preferred to `Promise.then`:

```
const result = await Promise.all(IDs[0].map(async id => {
    const data = await axios.get(`https://example-api.com/${id}`);
    return data.data.text;
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Async function inside a `foreach` loop doesnt wait for the axios response.

Try using `for-in` loop.

```
for (const id of IDs[0]) {
    URL = "https://example-api.com/" + id;
    const output = await axios.get(URL)
    result.push(output.data.text);
    console.log(result) // Returns the data       
})
```

Comment: Also you should not require the `then` statement.
The await operation directly returns the response of the asynchronous operation to the assigned variable.